# How to disable "update available in chromium" notification?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

How do you disable Chromium's "update available" notification spam?

In Gnome on Ubuntu, Chromium spams this notification at me several times a day and I can't find any way to turn it off. And I don't want to download and install a new version of Chromium every day. The new bugs that introduces negates any "security" fixes.

Google's docs to [disable this feature in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/227643814/i-want-to-disable-updates-on-google-chrome-for-mac?hl=en) do not work for Chromium, as the checkbox to disable auto-updates has been removed, or the UI is simply different for Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate running in a future date, by adding to your Chromium
invocation the following parameter:

```
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```